# Using Wildcard/Regex for find & replace in Visual Studio

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

I need to replace different values of `receiveTimeOut` attribute with a `receiveTimeOut="59:59:59"`
Can wild card search be used to achieve this task, in Visual Studio?

```
<endpoint receiveTimeOut="10:10:20" someOtherProperty="x1" yetAnotherProperty="y1" />
<endpoint receiveTimeOut="10:50:20" someOtherProperty="x2" yetAnotherProperty="y2" />
...
<endpoint receiveTimeOut="30:50:20" someOtherProperty="x3" yetAnotherProperty="y3" />
```

**I tried:** using wildcard option in Find & Replace dialog, `receiveTimeOut="*"` but this selects complete line, `receiveTimeOut="10:10:20" someOtherProperty="x1" yetAnotherProperty="y1" />`

As you might have guessed, I am editing WCF service web.config and have to do this task manually & repeatedly.

Comment: Which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: VS-2010, updated tag as well.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using the regex option...

Find: `<endpoint receiveTimeOut="[^"]+"`

Then...

Replace: `<endpoint receiveTimeOut="59:59:59"`

The `[^"]+` part uses a negative character class that matches any character except for a double quote. The `+` will match it one or more times.

Answer (score 4):

It turns out that this is actually quite simple to do with a regular expression.

Just use `.*` for your wildcard and check `Use regular expressions`.

For example, I have some grids and I want to find columns with an attribute of `Visible="False"` so a string might be:

```
telerik:GridBoundColumn name="name" Visible="False"
```

My search string would be: `"GridBoundColumn.*Visible="False""`

Done.

Comment: +1 for a very generically beneficial answer.  Note the spacing on this.  If you add spaces around `.*` (e.g. `foo<space>.*<space>bar`)then that becomes an extra space in the search which can cause the search not to find results.  Use precisely as shown in the answer therefore!

Answer (score 0):

Ahmad's is the way to go.  But as a naive and bit different alternative, one could search:

```
receiveTimeOut="[0-9]*\:[0-9]*\:[0-9]*"
```

This requires the data between the double quotes of the `receiveTimeOut` value has two colons (which are escaped) with any number of digits about them.

Comment: You're totally right--sorry about that.  I updated my response to at least be correct, if not actually helpful at this point.